# Use javascript to remove last digit from field onSubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the last digit from a form field when a user clicks submit using javascript.
e.g if I enter 1099 into a field with ID number, the value 109 would get submitted on submit.

Comment: just `.slice(-1)` from the value.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.slice(0, -1)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#formid").submit(function() {
    $("#fieldid").val(function() {
        return this.value.slice(-1);
    });
});
```